# Instagram API скачать видео при наличии объекта media

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Используя Instagram API я получаю объект media который содержит данные поста.

Получаю текст, картинки и прочее барахло.

Как скачать видео, которое прикреплено к этому посту? 
(в самом посте или в карусели, не важно. Нужен принцип как его достать)

Answer (score 0):

В новой версии [InstaSharper](https://github.com/a-legotin/InstaSharper/) появилось свойство InstaMedia.Videos в котором содержатся ссылки на прикрепленные к посту видео. Из свойств можно вытащить ссылку для скачивания реального видео из instagram